# GMB API - Payload schema for notification (pub/sub)

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

We are working with a google my business integration.

The API documentation is pretty exhaustive, except for the notification schema used on pub/sub.
we are unable to find the correct information.

Does anybody know what the data looks like?

[API docs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Notifications)

Comment: It's happen sometimes. In this case, I simply create a function that log the content of the notification and I work on this (or I search on internet similar piece of content for a more complete detail and optional attributes)

Comment: hi @guillaumeblaquiere we are doing almost the same :) ,retaining the messages on a test subscription, the only problem is the very high latency, it's been already 2 hours and no notification for now.
We deal mostly with reviews, hope one day they will fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new [Notifications API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/notifications/rest), you have the following basic pattern:

```
{
  "review":"accounts/*/locations/*/reviews/*",
  "location":"accounts/*/locations/*",
  "type":"NEW_REVIEW"
}
```

Q&A messaging is broken (more see [Google My Business push notification is not sent for Question and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442048/google-my-business-push-notification-is-not-sent-for-question-and-answers/69988133#69988133) ).

For GoogleUpdate messages, you will just get the type and location properties.