# Google My Business push notification is not sent for Question and Answers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

When a review reply is updated, I'm able to receive push notification. But where as for new question, update question and answer to a question is not notified via push notification. I subscribed to all changes.

URL: [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountno}/notifications](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7Baccountno%7D/notifications)

Output: [image]

I have given required permissions as well in pubsub settings

[image]

Comment: You can check the [Cloud Monitoring metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) `subscription/push_request_count` broken down by `response_class` or `response_code` to see if the messages are getting pushed to your endpoint and rejected, vs not pushed to your endpoint at all.

You can also check the metric `topic/publish_message_count` to make sure the messages are being published in the first place.

Comment: Did you solve this? Have similar problem.

Comment: were you able to figure out the cause this problem?

Comment: I recommend you to follow this [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting#messages), as where mentioned earlier is recommended to look in [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring) for errors related to the subscription in question.

Comment: According to GMB API docs =>https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/updateNotifications   `accounts.updateNotifications` can set pubsub notification settings only for: new reviews, updated review, new google update

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug.

I have reported this to the GMB API support multiple times - the new Notifications API has the same bug.
The four Q&A NotificationTypes (NEW_QUESTION, UPDATED_QUESTION, NEW_ANSWER, UPDATED_ANSWER) can be set, however GMB never sends Pub/Sub messages for them.

You can let them know here:
https://support.google.com/business/contact/api_default?hl=en

And hope that they create an issue here at some point:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:585921%20status:open

Comment: Seems many are waiting for solution. Thank you for the details.