# GMB PubSub trigger notifications with delay or not trigger

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api

1. I create topic.
2. Attach push-subscription with target to my server.
3. Set the email mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com as an administrator.
4. Update notification settings with valid topic name and next notificationTypes:

- GOOGLE_UPDATE
- NEW_REVIEW
- UPDATED_REVIEW
- NEW_QUESTION
- UPDATED_QUESTION
- NEW_ANSWER
- UPDATED_ANSWER

5. Did a test by manually posting a message and got the webhook successfully.

But, when I edit review reply - I recive part of events and with delay up to 30 minutes. Part of notifications don't receive.
If I try to write question or answer - I don't receive any events.

**Question:**

- why events do not come for questions
- why events are delayed
- how to fix the previous two points

Comment: try to submit a support ticket here => https://support.google.com/business/contact/api_default

Answer (score 0):

Concerning NEW_QUESTION, UPDATED_QUESTION, NEW_ANSWER, UPDATED_ANSWER, this is a bug (more see here [Google My Business push notification is not sent for Question and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442048/google-my-business-push-notification-is-not-sent-for-question-and-answers/69988133#69988133) ).

Concerning review updates, we are also seeing such delays. My guess is this is due to Google's publishing/QA pipeline where changes are first checked if they meet the guidelines before they are published globally. You yourself may see your changes right after editing, but that does not mean that the whole world will.

There's nothing you can do about either case, unfortunately.