# Q&A not coming in pub sub notification

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-cloud-pubsublite

The pub/sub notifications for Google Questions and Answers are not coming while the new reviews and google updates notifications are coming. Please let me know of any solutions

Comment: Can you add some documentation links of this process?

Comment: No @WytrzymałyWiktor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google My Business push notification is not sent for Question and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66442048/google-my-business-push-notification-is-not-sent-for-question-and-answers)